# jqueryui: How to skip page elements

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Super simple question: Is there a class I can add to an element to prevent jquery UI from altering it?

Comment: jQueryUI can do a lot of stuff. How exactly are you using it so that it is altering your element?

Comment: Another developer added a bunch of includes in the head. I'm fine with most of it, but sometimes it's just doing wacky things. Right now, I'm trying to align form elements and I can't add any of my own css rules. They get overridden as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can always define styling inline to override any sort of styling that occurs via spreadsheet. Or if you want to at least create a centralized place for them, you can make sure that they're the most recently called in `<style></style>` tags right before the `</head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, but in-line styles are overridden by the scripts. I tried that first.